# PropelBundle database:create for postgres

Tags: postgresql, symfony, propel

I've installed propel bundle for symfony2. 
my database configuration is:

```
propel:
    dbal:
        driver:               pgsql
        user:                 postgres
        password:             postgres
        dsn:                  pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test_database
        options:              {}
        attributes:           {}
```

When i wan to create this database from console (console propel: database:create) i have got strange error : `Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] FATAL: database "pgsql" does not exist.`

i created pgsql database on my localhost and everything was good. Database "test_database" was succesfull created. Can somebody explain me why i got this previous error? On mysql i've created database without any problems.

Comment: Without knowing propel, have you tried `pgsql:host=localhost;port=5432;dbname=test_database;user=postgres;password=postgres`?

Comment: Is your database in PostGre named "pgsql"?

Comment: DrColossos: , yes i've try but it didn't help.
Gabriel: when i create this database everything is ok , but i wonderind why, dbname is "test_database" not "pgsql"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was a bug in the PropelBundle, it has been fixed by the following commit (even if the commit message is about MySQL, it fixes other RDBMS): https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/commit/b4475d27fb1eb846d10cc2d2e2bd164f037508e3

Answer (score 0):

I 've installed new PropelBundle via Composer and everything is ok now. I think maybe it was a problem with 1.0 bundle , now I have 1.1

Comment: It was a [bug](https://github.com/propelorm/PropelBundle/issues/152) from PropelBundle and was fixed few days ago.